# Adding Labels to Divy side-navigation

Tags: html, css, wordpress, list, navigationbar

I'm setting up a website using wordpress and the Divy theme since I need to hand it off to someone who doesn't code once I'm done.

My issue is that I'm trying to add labels to the side-navigation bar that appear to the left of the dots on hover.
[Here](http://www.franzosini.ch/en/) is an example website with the same side navigation bar I'm working with.

The structure of the nav bar is this:

```
<ul class="et_pb_side_nav et-visible" style="margin-top: -100px;">
     <li class="side_nav_item">
       <a href="#" id="side_nav_item_id_0" class>0</a>
     </li>
     <li class="side_nav_item"><a href="#" id="side_nav_item_id_1" class="">1</a>
     </li>
     <li>
     etc...
     </li>
```

I've managed to thicken the bar on hover and keep the dots (a elements) in the same place with:

```
ul.et_pb_side_nav:hover {
   width: 100px;
}
ul.et_pb_side_nav:hover .side_nav_item a {
   margin-left: 60px;
   margin-right: 0px;
}
```

But I can't figure out how to make labels appear to the left of the dots.
I've tried many things along these lines:

```
ul.et_pb_side_nav .side_nav_item a#side_nav_item_id_0:before{
  content: “About Us”;
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

But haven't had any success. Any thoughts on how to get those labels there would be much appreciated. Thanks for any help!

UPDATE: [This person](http://www.divithemeexamples.com/custom-sidebar-navigation-in-divi/) managed to replace the dots with labels, but still haven't figured out how to keep the dots and only bring up those labels on hover, though it's helped me get closer.

Comment: I had an example ready but then you deleted the question last time. And I couldn't save it. Now it's gone.

Comment: oh no! Sorry Roy. I deleted it because I thought it was too broad (addressing both the movement of the dots and the insertion of the labels) so once I figured the dots out I thought it would be better etiquette to delete and re-post as a single question  so sorry for wasting all of your time and effort, I know how frustrating that is.

Answer (score 1):

Did you want something like this?

```css
ul {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  top: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
ul li.et_pb_side_nav {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: right;
}
ul li.et_pb_side_nav:after {
  content: "";
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 999px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  display:inline-block;
}
ul li.et_pb_side_nav a {
  font-size:0px;
  transition:all 180ms ease-in;
}
ul li.et_pb_side_nav:hover a {
  font-size:14px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="et_pb_side_nav"><a href="#">First</a>
  </li>
  <li class="et_pb_side_nav"><a href="#">Second</a>
  </li>
  <li class="et_pb_side_nav"><a href="#">Third</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Roy! That's exactly what I'm looking for in terms of effect. I played with your code a bit though and haven't been able to successfully implement it on the existing nav bar. the text appears under the existing white dot (which is made of the full a element, you can see what I mean by examining element on the site link I posted). I tried making the existing white dots disappear, but the text appears above the bullet made by your :after. All that said I think this gets me much closer! Thank you for your help!